# avoiding a possible null in android

Tags: android, forceclose

i have a situation where i may encounter a possible null, and i don't want my program to crash.  it is only happening for a small % of users and i'm not entirely sure why, but i know the section of code that is doing it.  basically the `isAchieved()` is a check that should return a boolean value, but in a few cases it is returning a null.  this is part of a scoreloop library and i have a suspicion the bug might be with their code.

rather than getting a force close and exiting the program is there a way to check if this value is going to return a null and simply skip over this section of code if that is the case?

```
if (_achievements[ltc].isAchieved()) {
   // Do stuff for 99.9% of users here, but skip if .isAchieved() would force close
}
```

Comment: Catch the exception? (Not recommended to catch runtime exceptions, which you seem to be aware of, but it's an option) You could also do an if statement. I.e. "if null, don't".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        boolean checker=false;
        try{
            checker=_achievements[ltc].isAchieved();
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e){
        }
        if (checker) {
           //content
        }
```

Did you think about doing that?.

Comment: that won't give me a NullPointerException for checker? i can't check it since it only happens to such a small number of users and i can't reproduce the error.

Comment: It wont give exception if the function is actually returning null. Other than that. Otherwise you have  to use try catch.